# sed replace dot dot slash, but e s slash got replace

Tags: regex, sed

OS : Debian Jessie 64
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

I have to replace my path from ../ to ../../  
Testing file.

```
$ cat dot.js 
path = '../'
```

I put backslash in front of slash to put in the single quote:

```
sed -i 's/..\//..\/..\//g' dot.js
```

Output :

```
path = '../../'
```

However, when I use with my actual file.

```
$ cat dotdot.js 
var real_questionHandler = require('../routes/questionHandler_delqid.js');
var questionHandler_delqid = proxyquire('../routes/questionHandler_delqid.js', { 'pg' : pgStub} );
```

Output :

```
var real_questionHandler = require('../../rout../../questionHandler_delqid.js');
var questionHandler_delqid = proxyquire('../../rout../../questionHandler_delqid.js', { 'pg' : pgStub} );
```

How can I protect second position of each line from replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape all the dots so that it would match the literal dot character or otherwise , unescaped dot would match any character. So that your regex matches `../` as well as `es/`

```
sed -i 's/\.\.\//..\/..\//g' dot.js
```

**or**

```
sed -i 's~\.\./~../../~g' dot.js
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo "require('../routes/questionHandler_delqid.js');" | sed 's~\.\./~../../~g'
require('../../routes/questionHandler_delqid.js');
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my new knowledge. I don't know that much about regex. I'm keep studying on it. (FYI my background is Physics and Math in CS)